# Python, MySQL not inserting when using variable. Can use exact value of variable in place, and it works

Tags: python, mysql

Have the following code:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import MySQLdb

if __name__=="__main__":

dbcon = MySQLdb.connect(host="host", port=3306, user="db", passwd="passwd", db="adki")
dbcur = dbcon.cursor()

deliveryCount = 0
bounceBadMailbox = 0
bounceInactiveAccount = 0
bouncePolicyRelated = 0
bounceSpamRelated = 0
bounceQuotaIssues =0

while True:
    #type, timeLogged,timeQueued,orig,rcpt,orcpt,dsnAction,dsnStatus,dsnDiag,dsnMta,bounceCat,srcType,srcMta,dlvType,dlvSourceIp,dlvDestinationIp,dlvEsmtpAvailable,dlvSize,vmta,jobId,envId,queue,vmtaPool
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    logList = line.split(',')
    bounceType = str(logList[0])
    if bounceType != "type":
        bounceType = str(logList[0])
        bounceCategory = logList[10]
        emailAddress = logList[4]
        jobId = str(logList[23])
        fwrite = open("debug.log","a")
        fwrite.write(jobId)

        if bounceType == "d":
            deliveryCount += 1
            fwrite = open("debug2.log","a")
            fwrite.write(str(jobId))
            dbcur.execute('UPDATE campaign_stat_delivered SET pmta_delivered = pmta_delivered + 1 WHERE id = ' + jobId)
            dbcon.commit()





fwrite = open("debug2.log","w")
fwrite.write("out of true loop")

dbcon.close()
```

New to python. This really stumps me.  The above SQL statement does not work (the value of pmta_delivered remains 0), but I can run:

```
dbcur.execute('UPDATE campaign_stat_delivered SET pmta_delivered = pmta_delivered + 1 WHERE id = ' + '42')
```

and it works!?!.  In 'debug2.log I have the value '42' written.  Whats going on??

database schema:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `campaign_stat_delivered`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `campaign_stat_delivered` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pmta_delivered` int(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `async_bounces` int(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `bad_mailbox` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `inactive_account` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `policy_related` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `spam_related` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `quota_issues` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

again I can change sql to be:

```
dbcur.execute('UPDATE campaign_stat_delivered SET pmta_delivered = pmta_delivered + 1 WHERE id = 1')
```

and it works fine.  really dumbfounded.

Comment: Probably you need to use `str(jobId)`.  However, it's hard to say because you don't explain *how* it doesn't work.  Do you get an error message?  If so, please include the entire error message in your post.

Comment: thought it might be issue of str or int (database is int).  It doesn't work in that it does not give pmta_delivered a value.  (I have tried both str and int, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Mind providing properly indented code at your question.

Comment: Not sure what you mean?  also, fyi just tried jobId='8', and that also is not providing pmta_delivered with a value.? :\

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you jobId is string showing integer value, I would propose

Add an assert, making sure, the string has nonzero length
Make sure, the string is in an integer format.

```
assert len(jobId) > 0
try:
    int(jobId)
except ValueError:
    print "ERROR: jobId is not in format of integer"
    raise
```

This is likely to tell you, what is the cause.

Comment: tried this, no error.  also tried just doing jobId='8', and it still does not do query.  Really not getting why this isn't working.

Comment: Tell us more - is there any error message around your execution? What exactly? Providing the schema of the table you are trying to update would show, what type is there expected. Any complains in database log file?

Comment: Updated question to show db schema.  Also gave SQL code that works fine.  There is no error.  Will look at db log.

Comment: is there a way I can log the response in python when it tries insert?  I have really tried every combination of everything I can think of!

Comment: so changing database to 'varchar', and doing jobid='4', I get an insert..so making progress, but as it stands now, getting actual "jobId" from my logList does not work.

Comment: MADE PROGRESS!  for some reason the debug BEFORE my if statement for bounceType=="d", it records the current active line being read.  for some reason AFTER the if statement, it is not being recorded until it gets to the second record.  so basically--it is one id AHEAD of what exists in the row, so it isn't able to write the entry, because it doesn't exist.  I have no idea why the jobid isn't in existence once the if statement is hit??